# How to forcefully make Device in landscape mode

Tags: iphone

I have and app in that app is running in potrait mode and when i go to the next wiew i have to change the device orientation in landscape mode. Is there any way.

Answer (score 1):

Put the below code in your controller class for having different orientation between UIViewControllers,

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  // Return YES for supported orientations
  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

You could also try with below having different orientation between views.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:@selector(setOrientation:) withObject:(id)UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

Answer (score 0):

No. `[UIDevice setOrientation:]` does that, but it's a private API.